# RegEx Replace at end of string using php

Tags: php, regex

I try to read chemical formulas like C6H12-1, C6H12-1(co2) using

```
"/(?i)\b[a-z]+(?:\d+[a-z]+)*\b/"
```

---

```
$fuel_value = preg_replace("/(?i)\b[a-z]+(?:\d+[a-z]+)*\b/","",$fuel);
print_r(implode($fuel_value));
```

It prints C6-H5(CH3) 15.0 ! ( ) as output, but i only want to read C6-H5(CH3) how can i eliminate data after space i.e  15.0 ! ( )

I tried to use $ but i failed. I am working on php for first time.

Apologize if my question is silly

Comment: enter your input and what is your output, you can only mentioned output **"C6-H5(CH3) 15.0 ! ( )"**

Comment: @Man Programmer : i am reading input from multiple text file and saved lines into variable $fuel.So the $fuel = FUEL C6H12-1 0.0 ! Fuel Fraction of Total Fuel Species (mole fraction) is input. From this line i need to read only formulas

Comment: is a comma separated or feed in next line

Comment: I have more than 5000 text files. Its not possible to use comma separated or to feed into next file

Comment: provide your sample small text it is easy to new regex

Comment: FUEL C6H12-1 0.0   ! Fuel Fraction of Total Fuel Species(molefr) 
FUEL C6H5CH3 15.0   ! Fuel Fraction of Total Fuel Species(molefr)
FUEL IC8H18 72.5   ! Fuel Fraction of Total Fuel Species(molefr)
FUEL NC7H16 12.5   ! Fuel Fraction of Total Fuel Species (molefr)
FUEL T124MBZ 0.0   ! Fuel Fraction of Total Fuel Species (molefr)

Comment: @Naveena Consider adding the example to your question, here is difficult to find.

Comment: +1 for making nice regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i use preg_match_all instead of preg_replace and list chemical formula's

```
$str = "FUEL C6H12-1 0.0 ! Fuel Fraction oFUEL C6H12-1 0.0 ! Fuel Fraction of Total Fuel Species(molefr) FUEL C6H5CH3 15.0 ! Fuel Fraction of Total Fuel Species(molefr) FUEL IC8H18 72.5 ! Fuel Fraction of Total Fuel Species(molefr) FUEL NC7H16 12.5 ! Fuel Fraction of Total Fuel Species (molefr) FUEL T124MBZ 0.0 ! Fuel Fraction of Total Fuel Species (molefr)";

preg_match_all("/[A-Z]+\d.*?[\s]/",$str,$match);

print_r($match);
```

Comment: Thank a lot. I was successful in doing my code $fuel= preg_grep("/FUEL /", $data);     

$str = implode($fuel);

preg_match_all("/[A-Z]+\d.*?[\s]/",$str,$match);

print_r($match);

Comment: I have written /[^0-9.]*/ to read value of formula ie 0.0 for C6H12-1 from text line "FUEL C6H12-1 0.0 ! Fuel Fraction of Total Fuel Species(molefr)" but print outputs 61210.0 instead of 0.0. can you please help me what regular exp should i use

Comment: try this regex will help you **/\b[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\b/**

Comment: preg_match_all("/\b[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\b/ ",implode($fuel),$match); IS WORKING Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I would use this:

```
FUEL ([\w\(\)-]+)
```

Here's a [demo](http://regex101.com/r/qS8iO1/2).

Comment: paste this on **FUEL C6H12-1 0.0 ! Fuel Fraction of Total Fuel Species (mole fraction) FUEL C6H5CH3 15.0** on test string then see what happen

Comment: @ManProgrammer Sorry i missed that, it was buried in the comments, now it works for the provided data.

Comment: they do'nt want to select FUEL see the expected output in above question